# How to fix second y-axis on combined bar and line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a combined bar and line plot. I've developed some code, but it seems like there is some problem with perhaps the range? The bars show up fine, but the line is too low on the graph and the second y-axis tick marks are missing. Does anyone know how I fix this?

```
#Entering Data
year <- c("2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022")
nike <- c(2.8, 3.1, 2.9, 3.1,  3.6, 4.7,  5.1)
jordan <- c(137.7, 154.9, 142.8, 156.9, 180.5, 235.6, 255.0)

data <- data.frame(year = year, nike = nike, jordan = jordan)
adjust <- 2000 # for adjusting second y-axis

# Plotting Charts and adding a secondary axis
library(ggplot2)
colors <- c("Jordan Brand Revenue (in $B)" = "black",
        "Michael Jordan Earnings (in $M)" = "red3") # For adding a legend.
ggplot(data, aes(x=year))+  
geom_col(aes(y = nike, color="Jordan Brand Revenue"), lwd = 1 , fill = "black") +
geom_line(aes(y = jordan/adjust, color="Michael Jordan Earnings"), lwd = 1.5, group                
= 1)+
scale_y_continuous(
name = "Jordan Brand Revenue (in $B)",
breaks = seq(0,6,1),
limits = c(0,6),
sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*adjust, name = "Michael Jordan Earnings (in $M)",
                    labels = scales::dollar,
                    breaks= seq(0,300,50))) +
theme_classic() +
scale_color_manual(values=colors)+
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "top")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `adjust` value is wrong. I changed it to 50.

Your initial value would've worked better if your data was actually in billions and millions, but the raw data really looks like the difference between a single digit value vs. a value in the hundreds. An easy way to figure out the best adjust is to do some basic algebra, with the number for the original y axis on the left and the number you want to correlate on the secondary axis on the right.
In this case, that looks like:

```
orig.x * adjust = orig.y
6 * adjust = 300
adjust = 300/6
adjust = 50
```

Here's the code:

```
adjust <- 50 # for adjusting second y-axis

ggplot(data, aes(x=year))+  
geom_col(aes(y = nike, color="Jordan Brand Revenue (in $B)"), lwd = 1 , fill = "black") +
geom_line(aes(y = jordan/adjust, color="Michael Jordan Earnings (in $M)"), lwd = 1.5, group = 1)+
scale_y_continuous(
name = "Jordan Brand Revenue (in $B)",
breaks = seq(0,6,1),
limits = c(0,6),
sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*adjust, name = "Michael Jordan Earnings (in $M)", labels = scales::dollar, breaks= seq(0,300,50))) +
theme_classic() +
scale_color_manual(values=colors)+
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "top")
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I change the line to red? I thought I covered that in the code, but for some reason it shows up gray. Also, how I get rid of the gray border on the bars?

Comment: Yeah, it's not working because you named the categories differently in the `colors` vector vs. when you labeled the `color` parameter in the `geom_*`s. I have fixed it in the above code

Comment: Thanks is there a way to add data labels to the line points? I tried adding this line of code, but it didn't work. geom_label(aes(label = Place, size = NULL), nudge_y = 0.7)

Comment: You need to include a `y` here. Try: `geom_label(aes(label = Place, y = jordan/adjust), nudge_y = 0.7)`

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there a way to make them read $137.7M?

Comment: Check out the [scales](https://scales.r-lib.org/) package or just use `paste`. I would do `geom_label(aes(label = paste0("$", Place, "M"), y = jordan/adjust), nudge_y = 0.7)`